# How to create a dynamic table in PHP/HTML? (MVC CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, html

This is an exercise but I can't do it.

I have tried this but I'm getting errors such as missing variable id/name.

Controller (User.php)

```
<?php

class User extends CI_controller {

    public function index() {
        $data['id'] = $id;
        $data['name'] = $name;
        $this->load->view('view_user', $data);
    }

    public function show($id, $name) {
        if ($id === NULL || $name === NULL) {
            echo "Error";
        } else {
            echo $id;
            echo "\n";
            echo $name;
        }
        $data['id'] = $id;
        $data['name'] = $name;
    }
}
```

View(view_user.php)

```
<?php
function get_table() {
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <th> ID </th>
            <th> Name </th>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <?php echo $id;?>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mean you're getting an undefined variable error? Where is your `get_table()` method located?

Comment: yes, undefined variable. The get_table() method is just a placeholder which isn't important as of now.